# The Response in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I use Jersey framework to implement restfull interface. And there have unusual phenomena. 
This is the interface.

```
 @GET
    @Path("/nini_response")
    public Response getMessageResponse() {
        // Just create a pdf file.
        OnePdf onePdf = new OnePdf();
        onePdf.createPdf(response);
        return Response.status(210).build();
    }
```

See, in the last code, I set the status to 210. I guess that will return 210 all the time.
But will it's success return PDF file, the status is 200, and when it throw exception, the status is 210.
Why?

Comment: what exception ?

Comment: No exception, I just wonder why it doesn't return 210 all the way.

Comment: This might be due to `onePdf.createPdf(response);`

Comment: onePdf.createPdf()--this method just create a pdf file. if success, return one pdf file, and fail, return some text. the reponse is HttpServletResponse.

Comment: exactly, so, when you get pdf, it means success, that also means 200.